# How to disable days is datepicker materializeCSS

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I am using materializeCSS datepicker and I only want to select Year and Months

I tried this. Also how to format the date. I want to have it's representation as 2017-07-20

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15,
  selectDays: false,
  today: 'Today',
  clear: 'Clear',
  close: 'Ok',
  closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field">
  <input type="date" class="datepicker" name="date" id="date">
</div>
```

Comment: I got the format part. Just wanna know how to disable days selection

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15,
  disable: [true],//disable days
  today: 'Today',
  clear: 'Clear',
  close: 'Ok',
  closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/scs7y96e/)